# Basic Julia Set

Tags: fractals, equations

I know how to generate a basic Mandelbrot fractal based on the system **Z -> Z + C**, which breaks down to:

X -> X² - Y² + A
Y -> 2XY + B

Is there a basic definition for a Julia set though on the same simple level, or at least a relatively simple level?

Comment: I've written a sum-up about the Mandelbrot/Julia difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29984188/216248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "classic" Julia set is described by Z<sub>n+1</sub> = Z<sub>n</sub> + C just as the Mandelbrot set.

However, while the Mandelbrot set starts with Z<sub>0</sub> = 0 and varies C across "the pixels", the Julia set varies Z<sub>0</sub> across "the pixels" and has a constant C throughout the set.

Comment: Now that is exactly the kind of useful information I need - very many thanks!